# $ u(x) = g(x) + \int_0^x f(x,t, u(t)) dt $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

$f: [0,k] \times [0,k] \times R \rightarrow R\ \ \ $ is continous in $ \{ (x,t,z) \in [0,k] \times [0,k] \times R , 0 \leq t \leq x \leq k \} $

$ g: [0,k] \rightarrow R \ \ $ is continous

And $\ \ \ | f(x,t,z) - f(x,t,y)| \leq C |z-y| \ \ \ \ $ for a $ 0 \leq C $

Now i have to show that the equation:
$$ u(x) = g(x) + \int_0^x f(x,t, u(t)) dt $$
has exactly one continous solution in $[0,k]$.

I have tried using the Banach fixed-point theorem but i dont know how.
is it the right approach at all?

Comment: Fixed-point theorem will work, when $[0,k]$ is small enough. When it is not, the local result can be extended to the whole segment using compactness.

Comment: Why it will work when [0,k] is small enough?

Comment: to use fixed point theorem one should introduce a functional space and an operator. The norm of corresponding operator depends on $k$, so it will be contracting only for small $k$.

Comment: And how do i introduce the right functional space and operator?

Comment: The answer is actually in your question. The space is $C[0,k]$ equipped with the uniform norm. The operator is the Volterra integral operator.

Comment: You can read about it in Arnold’s Ordinary Differential Equations, for example.

Comment: hm i dont get it...

Comment: Well, I think you're studying ODE, but it's necessary to know some basics from functional analysis when it comes to existence theorems.

Comment: The problem is that this result can't be proven in a few lines. Especially if it's necessary to introduce some terminology from functional analysis.

Comment: hm okay, thank you anyway.

Comment: And youre right im studying ODE, we introduced some basics from functional analysis but i never heard something of it before and im on a semester abroad so english is not my mother language.

Comment: I understand you :) Here's a quick explanation of my first statement: $$|u(x) - v(x)| = \left|\int_0^x \left[f(x,t,u(t)) - f(x,t,v(t))\right] dt\right| \leq \int_0^x \left|f(x,t,u(t)) - f(x,t,v(t))\right| dt \leq \int_0^x C|u(t)-v(t)| dt \leq \sup_{[0,k]}|u(t)-v(t)| Ck.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X =  C[0, k]$. Let us define $\Phi:X \rightarrow X$ by
\begin{align}
\Phi(w)(x) = g(x) = \int^x_0 f(x, t, w(t))\ dt. 
\end{align}
Indeed, $\Phi$ maps $X$ to $X$, since for any $0\le x \le y\le k$
\begin{align}
|\Phi(w)(x)-\Phi(w)(y)| \le&\ |g(x)-g(y)| + \left|\int^x_0 f(x, t, w(t))\ dt-\int^y_0 f(y, t, w(t))\ dt \right|\\
\le&\  |g(x)-g(y)| + \int^y_0|f(x, t, w(t))-f(y, t, w(t))|\ dt + \int^x_y|f(x, t, w(t))|\ dt \\
\le&\  |g(x)-g(y)| + \int^y_0|f(x, t, w(t))-f(y, t, w(t))|\ dt + \|f\|_\infty|x-y|.
\end{align}
Hence, by continuity of $f$, we see that $\Phi(w)(x)$ is also continuous which means $\Phi$ maps $X$ to $X$.

Next, let us show that $\Phi: X\rightarrow X$ is a contraction on $X$. Notice that

\begin{align}
\|\Phi(u)-\Phi(w)\|_\infty =&\ \sup_{x \in [0, k]}|\Phi(u)(x)-\Phi(w)(x)|\\
\le&\ \sup_{x \in [0, k]} \int^x_0 |f(x, t, u(t)) - f(x, t,w(t))| \ dt\\
\le&\ C\sup_{x, \in [0, k]} \int^x_0 |u(t) -w(t)|\ dt\\
\le&\ C k \|u -w\|_\infty.
\end{align}

However, we can't conclude that $\Phi$ is a contraction since $Ck$ doesn't necessarily need to be less than $1$. So, instead of proving $\Phi$ is a contraction on $X$, we can prove that $\Phi$ is a contraction on $[0, k_1]$ for some $k_1<k$ and $Ck_1<1$. Then, by Banach fixed point theorem, we know that there exists a unique $u$ defined on $[0, k_1]$ such that
\begin{align}
u(x) = g(x) + \int^x_0 f(x, t, u(t))\ dt 
\end{align}
for $x \in [0, k_1]$. Repeat the argument on the interval $[k_1, 2k_1]$. Since $[0, k]$ is compact, then we only need to repeat the argument a finite number of times. This shows that there is a unique $u \in C[0, k]$ that solves the above integral equation.